# How can I install a font from TexLive 2021 in 2022?

Tags: packages, texlive

I am using Pandoc to convert from Markdown to LaTeX and then to PDF. I am using the [Gentium](https://software.sil.org/gentium/) font family. TeX is installed using TeXLive 2022, and I have installed the `gentium-tug` package package. There is a known issue [discussed here](https://tug.org/pipermail/gentium/2023q1/000039.html) about characters with holes in them, as shown here from my file (note the holes in the `F`, `g`, and `e` characters:

[image: broken font]

I want to install an older version of the font package to see if that will fix the problem.
I downloaded the `gentium-*.tar.xz` files from `ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2021/tlnet-final/archive`, but I'm not sure what to do next.

How can I replace the currently-installed package version (from TeXLive 2022) with the old version from TeXLive 2021?

Comment: You can put the fonts into the expected directory location in your `texmf-local` or `texmfhome` directory. Then run `mktexlsr` (or Miktex equivalent) so that TeX find them. You mght also need to clear/update/rebuild the font cache. With `lualatex` the commands are `luaotfload-tool --cache=erase` and `luaotfload-tool -u` but I do not know what they are, outside of `lualatex`. If you prefer brute force, you can even over-write the existing fonts inside `texmf-dist` but this is NOT best. You will still need to update the font cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that changing from `pdflatex` to `xelatex` was the easiest way to handle this issue, because `xelatex` uses system fonts. The version of the font installed in Windows does not have these rendering issues.

I added `--pdf-engine=xelatex` to my command line invocation, and replaced `fontfamily: Gentium` with `mainfont: Gentium Plus` in the YAML frontmatter of my document.